# Python Matplotlib plotting sample means in bar chart with confidence intervals but looks like box plots

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, histogram, bar-chart, boxplot

I want to plot the means of four time-series into a Matplotlib bar chart with confidence intervals. Also I want to color them differently, to generate a bar chart like this [image]

So I wrote the following code:

```js
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(12345)
df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(-10, 200, 100), 
                   np.random.normal(42, 150, 100), 
                   np.random.normal(0, 120, 100), 
                   np.random.normal(-5, 57, 100)], 
                  index=[2012, 2013, 2014, 2015])
years = ('2012', '2013', '2014', '2015')
y_pos = np.arange(len(years))
df1_mean = df.iloc[0].mean()
df1_std = df.iloc[0].std()
df2_mean = df.iloc[1].mean()
df2_std = df.iloc[1].std()
df3_mean = df.iloc[2].mean()
df3_std = df.iloc[2].std()
df4_mean = df.iloc[3].mean()
df4_std = df.iloc[3].std()

value = (df1_mean, df2_mean, df3_mean, df4_mean)
Std = (df1_std, df2_std, df3_std, df4_std)

plt.bar(y_pos, value, yerr=Std, align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(y_pos, years)
plt.ylabel('Stock price')
plt.title('Something')
plt.show()
```

[image]

which gives me this (see the above). Not quite what I was expecting. Also, it looks like a box plot instead of a bar chart where each sample means should go all the way down to x-axis.

I admit I am really new to Matplotlib, but I really would like to know what's going on with my code. It's supposed to be a simple task, but I can't seem to get it. Should I invoke .subplots() command instead?
On top of that, I will really appreciate if someone would be kind enough to point me how to (1) add a horizontal line on the x-axis (say, on the value of 100) on the same bar chart as a threshold value, and (2) color these four bar differently (the exact color of choice doesn't really matter)?

Thank you.

Comment: Extending the bars to the bottom of the graph seems pretty arbitrary. What do you want the bar heights to signify then? A bar plot is usually made when it's meaningful to compare something to zero. If that's not what you need maybe you should consider other plot kinds like a boxplot.

Comment: I want bar height to represent sample mean with 95% confidence interval wrapped around the top of the bar.

Comment: Well in the accepted answer the y-coordinate of every bar's top represents the sample mean, and the bar height represents "how much higher this sample mean is than the all-time minimum value of all of data".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default the bars created by `plt.bar` start at `y=0`. For positive values they expand upwards, for negative they expand downwards.
You can have them start at a different value by using the `bottom` argument and add the amount of `bottom` to the values. This is done in the following code where I also brought the dataframe in a more usual shape (years are columns).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(12345)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[np.random.normal(-10,200,100), 
                   np.random.normal(42,150,100), 
                   np.random.normal(0,120,100), 
                   np.random.normal(-5,57,100)], 
                  columns=[2012,2013,2014,2015])

value = df.mean()
std = df.std()

colors=["red", "green", "blue", "purple"]
plt.axhline(y=100, zorder=0)
plt.bar(range(len(df.columns)), value+np.abs(df.values.min()), bottom=df.values.min(), 
        yerr=std, align='center', alpha=0.5, color=colors)

plt.xticks(range(len(df.columns)), df.columns)
plt.ylabel('Stock price')
plt.title('Something')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I sure did. Thanks again.

Comment: I'd add that to get the cross bar on top of the std lines use the `capsize` property of bar. To get the bars to touch one another, set bar width to 1.0

Comment: hey! thanks for this fantastic explanation, but how do we add vertical bars onto the end of the error bar (so it looks like two upside down T's)?

Answer (score 3):

you're looking for the confidence interval but .std() isn't doing that. You need to divide it by the sqrt of the population size and multiplying by the z score for 95% which is 1.96, before passing it to yerr. If you do that you won't need to adjust the bottom of the bars. I think you actually need to do more than that, like find the upper and lower bound of the interval but now we're stretching to the limits of my knowledge so I'll stop while I'm ahead.

Try this:

```
    xvals = range(len(df))
    yvals = df.mean(axis = 1).values
    y_std = df_transp.std()/np.sqrt(df_transp.shape[0])*1.96
    plt.bar(xvals, yvals, yerr=y_std, width = 0.5, capsize=15)
```